# Angular: ng-bind-html removing ng directives from HTML data fetched from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am saving data in firebase from WYSIWYG editor using angularJS. This data will be in HTML format.

I am fetching HTML data from firebase and with the help of angular directive ng-bind-html this HTML content is sanitized and text saved on the editor will be shown to the user. This text could contain text, images, links.

```
<div ng-bind-html="newHTML" ng-model="cleanText1"></div>
```

The HTML coming for data with link is in the below format:

```
<p>This is text editor <a href=\"http://someLink\">link</a><br></p>
```

Now if I click this link on the page it will redirect to the URL specified.But I want this link to open the page in a div which is to the right hand side of the page.
To prevent this behavior I replaced href with ng-href using code below:

```
$scope.newHtml=$scope.htmlcontent1.replace("href","ng-href");
$scope.newHTML=$sce.trustAsHTML($scope.newHtml);
```

Doing this ng-bind-html removed ng-href 
`<p>This is text editor <a>link</a><br></p>`  Which made it unclickable.

Also I have tried to add directive for a tag so that once user clicks this link I can give my own functionality instead of redirecting the user.

Directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('a', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {                                               
      var href = elem.children('a').attr('href');
      console.log("href"+href);
      elem.children('a').attr('href', null);
      elem.children('a').attr('ng-click', 'open()');
      $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
      console.log("elem"+elem.children('a').attr('href'));
      scope.open = function () {
        alert('1');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But directive is being called once the user clicks and is redirected to the new page.
Any ideas how to make this link open in right hand side of the page?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you replace the HTML from Firebase with the same hard-coded HTML, does it still have the same problem? If so, you can remove Firebase and AngularFire from the equation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for the help but I am afraid I need a little more, I replaced the HTML in firebase to 
<a ng-href="http://somelink">Link</a>
But ng-bind-html while rendering this HTML converts it to 
<a>Link </a>.
ng-bind-html is filtering out angular directives and keeping only HTML.

Is there a way to prevent ng-bind-html to filter angular directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make some tweaks in your code to get it in action.
Try this instead.

Make your own directive for sanitizing HTML in place of using ng-bind-html.

Replace

```
<div ng-bind-html="newHTML" ng-model="cleanText1"></div>
```

To

```
<div cleanHtml="newHTML" ng-model="cleanText1"></div>
```

cleanHTML will be a customized directive.
Make below directive in app.js to render HTML content.

```
 app.directive('cleanHTML',['$compile',function ($compile) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {

        return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
      },
      function(value) {
        console.log(value) 
        // Here you can see your HTML is going to get sanitized below
        element.html(value); 
        $compile(element.contents())(scope); // After this HTML will be sanitized.

      }
 )};
}])
```

Next is to suppress the behavior of href and apply a click function on the link so as to define your own functionality for the link.
Now replace this:

```
 $scope.newHtml=$scope.htmlcontent1.replace("href","ng-href");
$scope.newHTML=$sce.trustAsHTML($scope.newHtml)
```

To

```
$scope.newHtml=$scope.htmlcontent1.replace
("<a ","<a ng-click=\"$event.preventDefault();open()\"");
$scope.open = function()
   {
      alert("Whoa! It worked :)");
      //Write your code here
   }
```

This replacement will add ng-click to Link.
For e.g. if your HTML is like this

```
<a href="http://someLink">link</a>
```

It will become like this

```
<a ng-click="$event.preventDefault();open()" href="http://someLink">link</a>
```

$event.preventDefault() has been added to override href functionality so that ng-click functionality takes priority.

Now once you are able to make your link working after that comes the display part which is now a piece of cake.
You want that on click of that link content appears to the right hand side of the page.
You can fetch the content of the link and add in scope variable like this:

```
 $scope.newHtml=$scope.htmlcontent1.replace("<a ","<a ng-click=\"$event.preventDefault();open()\"");
      $scope.open = function()
      {
         alert("Whoa! It worked :)");
        //Write your code here
        //fetch the content in var content
        $scope.linkContent= content;
      }
```

use linkContent and add it  to the right hand side of the DIV of HTML page where you want to display and it's done :)

```
<div>{{linkContent}}</div>
```

Hope it works.
Happy Coding !!!